# Pentaho Field Name converting using predetemined alternative values

Tags: select, header, pentaho, transformation

Is it possible in Pentaho to convert the field name (header / column name) using JavaScript or another method? Currently I am migrating data of two different database systems which use other field name (column names). In the beginning of my migration project the function 'Select Values' was enough to rename each field name, but during the process the project became more complicated and the 'Select Values' option is time consuming and inefficient.

I am looking for a method that can convert the field name from the input (from database system 1) to a desired field name for output (for database system 2). For example by the use of a excel file with all field names from database system 1 (**FieldNameDB1**) in column 1 and the desired field names for database system 2 (**FieldNameDB2**) in column 2. The output files will be xls- or txt-files.

**Example given:** The field name that is used for the input of part numbers in database system 1  is 'partno'. In database system 2 the field name is 'PARTNUMBER'. The field name that is used for the input of the manufacturer in database system 1  is 'manuf'. In database system 2 the field name is 'MANUFACTURER'. Etc.

**FieldNameDB1  FieldNameDB2**

partno       PARTNUMBER

manuf        MANUFACTURER

sn           SERIALNUMBER

or_date      ORDERDATE

Database system 2 needs the header during the data-import, but there are 100+ different field names used in both databases. The 'Select Value' method is too time-consuming to apply on every new transformation.

Comment: Do you mean that the effort in changing the fieldname in the Select Value step is time-consuming OR the Pentaho "Select Value" step is not performing well ?? I am not clear on the "time-consuming" part of the question !!!

Comment: The effort in changing the fieldname in the Select Value step is time-consuming. This because most of the fieldnames need to be used in a lot of transformations. It would be very useful to automatically rename the fieldnames to the desired fieldnames using JavaScript or another method. In the upcoming project I need to make 50+ transformations with 200+ different fieldnames. In addition each transformation has a slightly different set-up, but most of the fieldnames will be found in  more than one transformation.

Answer (score 0):

Your best option is using the Select Values step but with Metadata Injection. A lookup table or file with old field names and new field names gives you the rename rules and then a metadata injection step changes the configuration of the Select Values step for each transformation, without the need to manually configure them.